# how to replace all substrings whose starting and ending is known

Tags: java, regex

The following string

```
"<service id="any value"></service>"
```

I want to replace it with the following using regex in java

```
 <service></service>
```

I have written the following but is not working if there are more than one service tag in the string

```
string.replaceAll("^<service.*</service>$", "<service></service>");
```

**Example :**

```
<request>
  <service id="anyvalue"></service>
  <service id="anyvalue"></service>
</request>
```

Comment: Another option is to use an XML parser.

Comment: Can't you just remove start and end symbols? (`^` and `$`)

Comment: @Shadov I have coded it manually. I am looking for alternate way through regex

Comment: Ye, I mean delete those symbols from your regex and it's gonna work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the regex without `^` and `$` in the start and end `<service.*</service>` so if you use :

```
string.replaceAll("<service.*</service>", "<service></service>")
```

result :

```
<request>
  <service></service>
  <service></service>
</request>
```

Comment: YCF_L is correct. Adding the ^ and $ don't take into account the leading white space on each line. In addition, you would have to turn on multi-line (?m); without it, ^ and $ match the entire string. Here is a link to a very helpful page: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html It allows you to test your regex.

Answer (score 0):

Use following regexp:

```
<service id=[^=]*<\/service>
```

It works correct with more than one service tag

See [here](http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=97878)

Answer (score 0):

Using regex to modify your xml is always going to be a problem, let us assume that your regex `<service.*</service>` works currently for your xml.
Later you want to update your xml to include a new attribute called `name` as :

```
<request>
  <service id="anyvalue" name="myservice"></service>
  <service id="anyvalue" name="myservice"></service>
</request>
```

and you want to remove `id` attribute only.

What do you think the regex will do ? It will remove `name` as well.

I would always use an xml parser to modify xml.

The following code would do it :

```
try
{
    String input = "<request><service id=\"anyvalue\"></service><service id=\"anyvalue\"></service></request>";
    InputSource inputSource = new InputSource( new StringReader( input ) );

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse( inputSource );

    NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("service");

    for ( int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++ )
    {
        Node node = nodes.item(i);
        if ( node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE )
        {
            Element element = (Element)node;
            element.removeAttribute("id");
        }
    }

    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty( OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml" );
    transformer.setOutputProperty( OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "true" );

    DOMSource xmlSrc = new DOMSource( doc.getDocumentElement() );
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    transformer.transform( xmlSrc, new StreamResult( sw ));
    System.out.println( "Modified xml is : " + sw.toString() );       

}
catch ( Exception e )
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```